# Connecting Multi MPU6050 using I2C on ESP32 Wroom 32D

Tags: esp32, i2c, mpu6050

I want to connect two MPU6050 sensor on Esp32 using the I2C protocol.

ESP32 to MPU6050 connection, I'm using -

```
VCC(ESP32) - VCC(MPU6050_1) - VCC(MPU6050_2)                
GND(ESP32) - GND(MPU6050_1) - GND(MPU6050_2)                                                   
G21(ESP32) - SDA(MPU6050_1) - SDA(MPU6050_2)                                             
G22(ESP32) - SCL(MPU6050_1) - SCL(MPU6050_2)              

3V (ESP32) - AD0 (MPU6050_2)
```

and both the MPU6050 device are also detected by the I2C scanner program
0x68 , 0x69

but when the basic reading program to read for MPU6050 data , one MPU6050 is giving zero value for all accelerate axis and gyro axis.

// Basic demo for accelerometer readings from Adafruit MPU6050

```
#include <Adafruit_MPU6050.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Wire.h>

Adafruit_MPU6050 mpu1;
Adafruit_MPU6050 mpu2;

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial)
    delay(10); // will pause Zero, Leonardo, etc until serial console opens

  Serial.println("Adafruit MPU6050 test!");


  // Try to initialize!
  if (!mpu1.begin(0x68)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to find MPU6050 chip1");
    while (1) {
      delay(10);
    }
  }

  if (!mpu2.begin(0x69)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to find MPU6050 chip2");
    while (1) {
      delay(10);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("MPU6050 Found!");

  mpu1.setAccelerometerRange(MPU6050_RANGE_8_G);

  mpu1.setGyroRange(MPU6050_RANGE_500_DEG);
  
  mpu1.setFilterBandwidth(MPU6050_BAND_21_HZ);

  mpu2.setAccelerometerRange(MPU6050_RANGE_8_G);

  mpu2.setGyroRange(MPU6050_RANGE_500_DEG);
  
  mpu2.setFilterBandwidth(MPU6050_BAND_21_HZ);
  
  Serial.println("");
  delay(100);
}

void first() {

  /* Get new sensor events with the readings */
  sensors_event_t a, g, temp;
  mpu1.getEvent(&a, &g, &temp);

  Serial.println("Sensor 1");

  /* Print out the values */
  Serial.print("Acceleration X: ");
  Serial.print(a.acceleration.x);
  Serial.print(", Y: ");
  Serial.print(a.acceleration.y);
  Serial.print(", Z: ");
  Serial.print(a.acceleration.z);
  Serial.println(" m/s^2");

  Serial.print("Rotation X: ");
  Serial.print(g.gyro.x);
  Serial.print(", Y: ");
  Serial.print(g.gyro.y);
  Serial.print(", Z: ");
  Serial.print(g.gyro.z);
  Serial.println(" rad/s");

  Serial.print("Temperature: ");
  Serial.print(temp.temperature);
  Serial.println(" degC");

  Serial.println("");
  delay(500);
}

void second() {

  /* Get new sensor events with the readings */
  sensors_event_t a, g, temp;
  mpu2.getEvent(&a, &g, &temp);

  Serial.println("Sensor 2");

  /* Print out the values */
  Serial.print("Acceleration X: ");
  Serial.print(a.acceleration.x);
  Serial.print(", Y: ");
  Serial.print(a.acceleration.y);
  Serial.print(", Z: ");
  Serial.print(a.acceleration.z);
  Serial.println(" m/s^2");

  Serial.print("Rotation X: ");
  Serial.print(g.gyro.x);
  Serial.print(", Y: ");
  Serial.print(g.gyro.y);
  Serial.print(", Z: ");
  Serial.print(g.gyro.z);
  Serial.println(" rad/s");

  Serial.print("Temperature: ");
  Serial.print(temp.temperature);
  Serial.println(" degC");

  Serial.println("");
  delay(500);
}

void loop(){

  first();

  delay(1000);

  second();
  
}
```

All connection and config are correct both still MPU6050 sensor two not giving the correct data.

I request you to please check and see, what wrong I'm doing in it.

Serial Monitor -

```
Adafruit MPU6050 test!                                                             
MPU6050 Found!                                          
                                  
Sensor 1                                            
Acceleration X: -2.18, Y: 1.27, Z: 9.20 m/s^2                        
Rotation X: 0.23, Y: 8.34, Z: 2.97 rad/s                           
Temperature: 31.69 degC                                    
                                   
Sensor 2                             
Acceleration X: 0.00, Y: 0.00, Z: 0.00 m/s^2          
Rotation X: 0.00, Y: 0.00, Z: 0.00 rad/s
Temperature: 36.53 degC

Sensor 1
Acceleration X: -2.21, Y: 1.29, Z: 9.17 m/s^2
Rotation X: 0.06, Y: 8.29, Z: 2.96 rad/s
Temperature: 31.70 degC

Sensor 2
Acceleration X: 0.00, Y: 0.00, Z: 0.00 m/s^2
Rotation X: 0.00, Y: 0.00, Z: 0.00 rad/s
Temperature: 36.53 degC
```

Comment: please add the content of the serial monitor ... copy and paste, then format same as code ... NO pictures please

Comment: @jsotola , I added the serial monitor data in the question lower sections, please check above.
actually, the Sensor 1 (MPU6050) data is correct but the sensor 2 (MPU6050) data is showing zero only.

Comment: you forgot to format as code ... did it for you

Comment: swap the modules ... what is the resulting data?

Comment: Same results as previous , sensor which AD0 pin connected to 3.3V is giving Zero values.